# I am trying to code a searchbar using react native with API calls. I'm getting an Axios error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am new to react native and am I trying to code a search bar with API calls. Every time I run the code I get a fetching data error. Could anyone help me please?

Here is my code:

When running the code it gives me the following error:

> Error Fetching Data: AxiosError: error failed with status code 404.
> Could anyone please help me? Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import axios from 'axios';

function Menu(props) {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

    const rapidApiKey = "****************p1dfd12jsnf2823d3248e8"; // Replace with your actual RapidAPI key

    const handleSearch = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com/search', {
                headers: {
                    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com',
                    'X-RapidAPI-Key': rapidApiKey,
                },
                params: {
                    q: searchText,
                },
            });

            setSearchResults(response.data.results);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            console.log('Error response:', error.response); // Log the detailed error response
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        handleSearch(); // Fetch initial data when the component mounts
    }, []);

    return (
        <ScrollView vertical showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.search}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder='Search'
                        placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                        clearButtonMode='always'
                        autoCapitalize='none'
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        style={styles.searchBar}
                        value={searchText}
                        onChangeText={(text) => setSearchText(text)}
                        onSubmitEditing={handleSearch}
                    />
                    <Ionicons name='search' size={25} color={'#8E43ED'} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.suggestion}>
                    {searchResults.map((result) => (
                        <View key={result.id} style={styles.suggestionBox}>
                            <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{result.name}</Text>
                            {/* Add other relevant data fields */}
                        </View>
                    ))}
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#333',
        padding: 10,
        paddingTop: 50,
    },
    search: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginBottom: 20, // Added margin to separate the search bar from suggestions
    },
    searchBar: {
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        borderBottomColor: '#8E43ED',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        color: '#fff',
        width: '80%', // Adjusted width for better alignment
    },
    suggestion: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        gap: 50,
    },
    suggestionBox: {
        backgroundColor: '#8E43ED',
        width: 150,
        height: 200,
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 8,
    },
});

export default Menu;
```

Comment: API you are calling doesn't exist. Check the specification.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code 404 Stands for Method Not Found. This means that there is no API endpoint that corresponds to the provided method signature.

In your case

```
const handleSearch = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com/search', {
            headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'worldwide-restaurants.p.rapidapi.com',
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': rapidApiKey,
            },
            params: {
                q: searchText,
            },
        });

        setSearchResults(response.data.results);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        console.log('Error response:', error.response); // Log the detailed error response
    }
};
```

You are trying to reach for a search endpoint that does not tally with the method body you are passing. Check the Subsequent HTTP endpoint (search endpoint for its method signature) and specify the parameter and URL properly.

> Read more about 404 Http status code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)